# getting a view using getResources()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to set text of a TextView that is inside a layout file,
I tried setContentView() but it isnt working since i am using fragments.
I tried using getResources().getLayout(R.layout.abc);
It returns null

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: how are you initializing variable..

Answer (score 1):

> I tried setContentView() but it isnt working since i am using
>   fragments

That's wrong. You have to override `onCreateView` and inflate and return the layout you want to show, and you can use `onCreateView`, and use its first parameter, `View view`, to call `findViewById` and access the widgets in your layout. You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) and [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle))

Comment: Thanks for your help,but I want to know can I use getResources().getLayout()

Comment: `getResource().getLayout()`? what for ?

Comment: I mean using getResources() i reach to res folder then using getLayout() I reach to a certain layout file ,then to a view...

Comment: you are doing that in `onCreateView` when you call `inflater.inflate`.

Answer (score 1):

inside fragment you can set view inside function onCreateView(), use below code

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle b) {
         View view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
         return view;
     }
```

here my_layout should be the name of layout file,

now you can get view of it inside function onviewcreated()

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
  // here you can get your textview and set its value
}
```

thumbs up, if you find my answer correct

Answer (score 1):

You can inflate your layout like this:

```
ViewGroup group = LayouInflate.from(context).inflate(R.layout.abc,null);
TextView tv = group.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to inflate the layout through the onCreateView method and then return the View.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
        TextView yourTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
        return rootView;
    }
```